# mongoose post without duplications

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, strict

I am trying to look at a post/create that does not allow multiple instances in the database(so no duplicates). I looked at the `updateOne` with an `{upsert:true}` and this won't work for me because that only works if you have a specific set of data.

example data:

```
cat:{
    name: "jim",
    age: 8
}
```

example model :

```
cat:{
    name: String
}
```

the code I had :

```
object.updateOne(req.body,req.body,{upsert:true},function(err,object){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    res.json(object);
})
}else{
    res.json('error: type: '+ req.params.type + 'not found !');
}
```

but this only works if I add `'age'` to my model. due to the `{strict:true}` policy on the `updateOne`. and when I use a post I get multiple instances of the same object.

so hopefully someone can help me. ( and if someone knows a better title for this problem , please comment it below). I didn't know how to describe my problem with 1 sentence.

(keep in mind that in reality I have a dataset of 100+ attributes and only need 60). so simply adding age wouldn't help for my dataset. because then I have 40 unused values in my document.

**Edit:**
 after looking at code posted as an answer below i noticed that i made an error in my own code. this is how the code is supose to be :

```
  object.updateOne({},req.body,{upsert:true},function(err,object){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        res.json(object);
    })
    }else{
        res.json('error: type: '+ req.params.type + 'not found !');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `strict:false` in `update` query. They may help to solve your problem.

```
var data = { fieldOne: 'Test2', fieldTwo: 'Test3' };
var opts = {
  upsert: true,
  runValidators: false,
  strict: false
};
Model.update({}, data, opts)
  .then((success) => {
    //success
  }).catch(() => { 
    //error 
  })
```

Comment: this does not work for me. because now age gets added aswell.

Comment: So, what you need? age get discard?

Comment: in a normal post request you can use the model as a filter for the attributes that you want. i have to use that system only without any duplicates. so in this example i only want the name to be in the database. ( in reality i need 60 of the 100 attributes of an object )

Comment: Thank you , after looking at this again. i noticed i did something wrong in my own code. i put in the req.body twice by accident. so the query searches for attributes that arent in the model. dumb me >_<